# How can I make my code in compliance with MISRA 2012 RULE 2.1

Tags: c, switch-statement, default, break, misra

Code:

```
switch(abc)
{
    case i_a:
        temp = adc(channel_1);
        return temp *(-1);
        break;  //Line 6

    case i_b:
        temp1 = adc(channel_2);
        return temp1;
        break;   //Line 11
    default:
        return 0;
}
```

The break at line 6 and 11 becomes unreachable because there is a return before the break statement.

PC Lint throws the error "Unreachable code at token "break" Misra 2012 RULE 2.1 . How can I resolve it ?

Comment: Just remove the `break`?

Comment: Remove the `break` statements (though that might break some other of MISRA's overly strict rules)? Or refactor the code so that you use only a single variable that is assigned in the cases, and returned after the `switch`?

Comment: It will give rise to another error. Can't remove break.

Comment: @user3340164: I believe rule 14.7 says you cannot have more than one return inside a function, so you will have to rewrite this anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Either remove the `break` or rewrite the code as for example:

```
switch(abc)
{
    case i_a:
        temp = adc(channel_1);
        temp= temp * -1;
        break;

    case i_b:
        temp = adc(channel_2);
        break;

    default:
        temp= 0;
        break;
}
return temp;
```

Comment: In case 1 the temp is multiplied with -1 where as in case 2 its is the same. How can i solve it now ?witch(abc)
{
    case i_a:
        temp = adc(channel_1);
        break;

    case i_b:
        temp = adc(channel_2);
        break;

    default:
        temp= 0;
        break;
}
return temp;

Comment: I don't see that in your code. I don't understand what you ask.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie's solution is good, but please add a `break` on the `default` case.  Although strictly unnecessary, it's good practice to include and insulates you from bugs when the code changes later in life.

Comment: @EddInglis: with all warnings enabled (`-Wall -Werror -Wextra`) issues like these should be nonexistent in practice. Gcc is also smart enough to [ignore this warning for the default case](https://godbolt.org/z/CTCM-W).

Comment: Well, then just do the multiplication of `temp` in the `case` part, `temp= temp*-1;` Or is that too difficult?

Comment: @user3340164: so, you are asking how to multiply `temp` with `-1`?

Comment: @Groo, you're quite right, but better to do it 'right' in the first place.  Plus, honestly, how many beginners do you think use `-Wall`?

Comment: @Groo I have edited the question. Now how can I rewrite to solve the error.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm learning C. Take it easy. Dint think to rewrite the code. Was just working on how to solve the problem.

Comment: The code in this answer is MISRA compliant. MISRA-C:2012 `switch` syntax is strict though, so removing break isn't an option. Using a temporary variable as shown here is the normal way to deal with this. Usually named `result`, being the result of the function.

Comment: @user3340164 If you are learning C, then you should stay clear of MISRA-C. It requires quite a bit of C knowledge to be used.